# C# Array index out of bounds error

Tags: c#, .net

**Full disclosure**: This is for a homework assignment.

This is driving me nuts.  I'm writing a Discrete Cosine Transform function and have it basically complete, but I'm running into an IndexOutOfRange exception.

Code is below:

```
static int[][] DiscreteCosineTransform(int[][] pIn)
        {
            int[][] cosP = pIn;
            double SumCosP = 0;
            double Cx = 0;
            double Cy = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Discrete Cosine Transformed Array:");
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    Cx = 1 / Math.Sqrt(2);
                else
                    Cx = 1;
                for(int j = 0; j < 8; i++)
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                        Cy = 1 / Math.Sqrt(2);
                    else
                        Cy = 1;

                    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
                        {
                            SumCosP += cosP[x][y] * Math.Cos(((2 * x + 1) * i * Math.PI) / 16) * Math.Cos(((2 * y + 1) * j * Math.PI) / 16);
                        }
                    }
                    pIn[i][j] = (int)(0.25 * Cx * Cy * SumCosP);
                    Console.Write(" " + pIn[i][j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            return pIn;
        }
```

Where pIn is:

```
int[][] P = new int[][]
            {
                new int[]{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
                new int[]{10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10},
                new int[]{10,20,30,30,30,30,20,10},
                new int[]{10,20,30,40,40,30,20,10},
                new int[]{10,20,30,40,40,30,20,10},
                new int[]{10,20,30,30,30,30,20,10},
                new int[]{10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10},
                new int[]{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}
            };
```

Comment: What line of code is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This line

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; i++)
```

should read

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 

                      ^
```

Comment: +1 ... D'oh! Well, these things happen. Thanks for helping me fix my silly mistake!

Comment: @MachinationX: Don't just fix the mistake. Ask yourself "what factor caused me to make this mistake and how can I never, ever do it again?"  The factor that led to the mistake was the use of meaningless and visually almost-identical variable names i and j. Can you come up with names for i, j, x and y which are descriptive and less likely to be easily confused for each other?

Comment: I agree with Eric. Variables called i,j,x and y make it so much more difficult to spot a problem like this, especially when i and j look very similiar in fixed-width fonts like courier.  If you can give them short, relevent names you'd have found this issue before needing to post :) Best of luck with your project/hw however.

Answer (score 3):

You did:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; i++)
```

And most likely meant:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
```

(You did **i**++, not **j**++.)

Answer (score 1):

change i to j at this line
`for (int j = 0; j < 8; i++)`